# Self insulted in front of someone

Tags: word-usage, sentence-usage

It feels good to be self insulted.

How to say it grammatically correct. I know I am wrong please make me correct.

Comment: It is very difficult to tell you how to say something correctly if you don't tell us what it is you want to say.  What is the meaning of what you're trying to say?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what exactly you want to say with *self-insulted*. Why would anyone want to insult themselves or be humiliated in front of others? That's a form of masochism. Maybe, you're thinking of something like [**self-criticism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-criticism) or [**self-deprecation**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-deprecating) which are generally considered good qualities to have. And those are probably the expressions you're looking for.

Examples:

> **Self-criticism** is a good quality to have because it helps you see yourself from a more critical position.
>
> It's always good to be a little bit **self-deprecating** in whatever you do.

Comment: No actually I wanted to say that in a fun way that. I always take approval from my friend before uploading my photos on social media cause sometimes it feels good to get self insulted.

Comment: Actually my English is not as good as you people, so I couldn't explain I just want to say that "it feels good to be humiliated by yourself" is that what I am trying to say.

Comment: Well, then just say exactly that: **I really like it when people humiliate me.** or **I enjoy being humiliated.**

Comment: It perhaps means when people does, but I wanted to translate like "I like to be get self humiliated or something" a kind of by my choice it's happening

Comment: **I like being pushed around** -- will that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

"Self-insulted" implies you are insulting yourself.  If that's the case then Cookie Monster's answer of "self-deprecation", etc. would apply.

Otherwise, if you're just talking about someone else insulting you *publicly*, then that's pretty much what you would (sarcastically) say:

> It's always fun **to be abused by my friends**.
>
> Could you please **slap me around** some more?  I really enjoy it!

Or you can focus on the expected *result* of the insults:

> I always appreciate **being humiliated in front of an audience**

Certain well-known political figures or celebrities will sometimes be given a *roast*, which is a banquet at which the honoree is subjected to good-natured ridicule by other celebrities, often famous comedians.  For example, [excerpts from the 2009 Roast of President Obama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3OGxBsImls).

In this context, it may be OK to say you're being "roasted" by your friends, but I don't know if they'd understand.

Comment: What if I say, it feels good to being humiliated by yourself.

Comment: @fusion then *self-deprecation, self-denigration, self-abuse, self-humiliation, etc.* as in the previous answer.